# How to place 2 text inputs on a single row in a nested fluid-layout with Twitter Bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, fluid-layout

I'm trying to create a layout where my textboxes fill the column that they are in.  In this example I have a "ContactBlock_FirstName" and "ContactBlock_LastName".  I'm expecting them to appear on the same row each taking up 50% of the row they are in.

As you can see from the code below I'm using fluid rows with a high level container of (2 x 10 columns).  Inside the span10 I've got my control-group and I split it so that each input has 6 columns (since I'm using a fluid layout nested rows should should always add to 12).

Can anybody tell me why the textboxes appear on 2 rows even though their width appears correct.  Here is a screenshot of the output.  http://screencast.com/t/XEziHbs7X

I'm switching from Foundation Grid to Bootstrap so there may be some other issues with my layout feel free to point them out.  Thanks!

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span2">
            <h3>
                Left Nav</h3>            
        </div>
        <div class="span10">
            <form>
            <h3>
                Body</h3>
            <div class="row-fluid">
                <div class="span6">
                    <h4>
                        Column A</h4>
                    This is just same plain text. This is just same plain text. This is just same plain
                    text. This is just same plain text. This is just same plain text. This is just same
                    plain text. This is just same plain text. This is just same plain text. This is
                    just same plain text. This is just same plain text.
                </div>
                <div class="span6">
                    <h4>
                        Column B</h4>
                    This is just same plain text. This is just same plain text. This is just same plain
                    text. This is just same plain text. This is just same plain text. This is just same
                    plain text. This is just same plain text. This is just same plain text. This is
                    just same plain text. This is just same plain text.
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label">
                    Name<span class="required">*</span></label>
                <div class="controls controls-row">
                    <input class="span6 required" id="ContactBlock_FirstName" name="ContactBlock.FirstName"
                        placeholder="First Name" type="text" value="" />
                    <input class="span6 required" id="ContactBlock_LastName" name="ContactBlock.LastName"
                        placeholder="Last Name" type="text" value="" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-actions">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                    Save</button>
                <a href="#" class="btn">Cancel</a>
            </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

New answer
It seems to be the margin on the left thats breaking it.  You can manually change this with css (you'd need to use media queries for the different sizes though.  An example would be like this

```
#ContactBlock_LastName
{
   margin-left:0px;  /* or whatever value you think looks best */
}
```

#### OLD ANSWER

Your controls-row isn't fluid so the you'll want the inputs to be span5, span 5 to fill up to 10 rather than to 12.  non fluid rows add up to their total space, not to 12.

Comment: That doesn't seem correct.  If I use span5 then the width of the text box doesn't match the columns above.  As shown in this screenshot...  http://screencast.com/t/WPZ4mvcuBQH

Comment: Interesting, I've never mixed fluid and non-fluid pieces before.  I'm playing with it now and it appears to be the margin on the left thats breaking it.  If you set margin-left on the input to 0 it works

Comment: Agreed.  I think I'll just not use the controls-row.  If I put each input in its own <div class="span6"> and then use ".span12" for input control it renders as desired.  Neither is fix is ideal:(  Thanks for looking into it!

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @ben336 this looks like an issue because controls-row isn't fluid.  His suggestion should work fine I've decided for the time being to go with this...  Please feel free to suggest changes to this answer as well.

```
    <div class="row-fluid control-group">
        <label class="control-label">
            Name<span class="required">*</span></label>
        <div class="controls">
            <div class="span6">
                <input class="span12 required" id="ContactBlock_FirstName" name="ContactBlock.FirstName"
                    placeholder="First Name" type="text" value="" />
            </div>
            <div class="span6">
                <input class="span12 required" id="ContactBlock_LastName" name="ContactBlock.LastName"
                    placeholder="Last Name" type="text" value="" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```